# Why default argument constructor is called as default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

```
Class A {
public:
       A(int i = 0, int k = 0) {} // default constructor WHY ??
       ~A() {}
};
int main()
{
  A a; // This creates object using defined default 
       // constructor but the constructor still has two arguments
  A b(1,2); // Called as parametrized one
}
```

Why this default argument constructor is default constructor. Why it is not called Parametrized constructor or default parametrized constructor because even if this constructor is called with no arguments it does contain two arguments ?? Is there any specific reason or its just because the standard says so.

Comment: "Why it is not called Parametrized constructor?" - it is. But it's also a default constructor, since it *can* be called without (explicit) arguments.

Comment: why not call it Default parametrized constructor ??

Comment: @Tejendra: Call it if you want to call it so. The Standard calls it what-is-called.

Comment: "why not call it Default parametrized constructor ??" - yes, you can call it that, since that's what it is. You seem to think that, being a default constructor, you  can't call it anything other than a default constructor. That's not the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> #### C++11 §12.1 Constructors
>
> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument.

This is the definition of default constructor. A constructor that supplies default arguments for all its parameters **can** be called without argument, thus fits the definition.

Comment: I already know this thing..but can you please elaborate the WHY part ?? Is it only because the standard says so ??

Comment: @Tejendra Sorry to disappoint you, but yeah, because the standard says so. It can be used in places where a default constructor is expected.

Comment: @Tejendra How would you resolve the ambiguity if it were any other way?

Answer (score 5):

By definition, a default constructor is one that **can be called** without arguments. Yours cleary fits that definition, since both parameters have default value.

The asnwer to "why" is, I'd say, simply because C++ standard says so. The choice of constructor to be called is done by overload resolution based on number and types of parameters, just like with other functions.

Answer (score 1):

The feature of constructor overload allow the compiler to infer which constructor to call based on the passed arguments.
The default constructor is just the constructor which is resolved for no arguments, as in

```
A a;
```

or

```
A a=A();
```

And again due to parameters overloading only a single constructor can be resolved for each set. So, if all parameters have default values => it is ok to call 'A()' => it is the default constructor.

Comment: Note that the two declarations you wrote have different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

According to c++ standard a default constructor is the one which can be called without arguments.It is also the reason for your quesrion.